# Подключение субтитров

Tags: html5

Не получается подключить субтитры к видео. Видео работает а субтитров нет.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>VideoSub</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
        <video id="video" controls width="500" height="500" src="video/prostomp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <track default kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="video/sub.vtt"></track>
        </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а консоль разве не пишет что-то типа **Text track from origin has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute.** ?  Поставьте Xampp, добавьте  **crossorigin="anomymous"** к тегу **video** и радуйтесь. Иначе CORS  Вам не даст загрузить файл .vtt